# Deriving a property regarding variance.

Tags: probability, actuarial-science

I am studying for the P-exam for actuaries and I've encountered a property that said,

> $Var(x\pm y)=Var(x)+Var(y)$

I come from a math major and it has been years since I was taught statistics or probability, so I wanted to prove this using another property that I am comfortable using

> $E[X^2]-(E[X])^2=Var(X)$

Using this definition, I actually got

> $Var(x \pm y)= Var(x)+Var(y)\pm 2(E[XY]-E[X]E[Y])$

However, I was not able to confirm that the last two terms are equilavent to each other. I was thinking that independence in the random variables $X$ and $Y$ were the key, but my book is more of a problem set book, so it did not give me enough info to show it.

I also tried to look around online, but now the formula was too general and it was a bit above my head.

Can someone help me out ?

Comment: are X,Y independent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is $Var(X\pm Y)=Var(X)+ Var(Y)\pm 2Cov(X,Y)$ .

If two variables are uncorellated then $Cov(X,Y)=0$ (Note that if two variables are independent then they are uncorellated but not the opposite)

For the covariance you can find more information [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance)

Comment: Okay, so I was not crazy.  Thank you for leading me the way.

Comment: I just wanted to ask a follow up question.  I saw that $E(xy)=E(x)E(y) because f_{x,y}(x,y)=f_x(x)f_y(y)$ when x and y are independent.  Does this mean that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{ \infty}xyf_{x,y}(xy)dxdy= \int_{-\infty}^{infty}xf_x(x)dx \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}yf_y(y)dy$ ?

Comment: yes this is the general idea!

Answer (score 2):

The variance of a sum (or difference) is *not necessarily* the sum of the variances. But the result does hold if the two random variables are *independent*, or, more weakly, uncorrelated.

To prove the result (say for sums) in the case $X$ and $Y$ are independent, we can proceed as you did. If $X$ and $Y$ are independent, then $E(XY)=E(X)E(Y)$, which finishes things.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I was just wondering why when X and Y are independent the expected value of a product was the product of expected values. I will look it up, though.

Comment: It takes some work in general. But for instance suppose $X$ and $Y$ are independent with densities $f$ and $g$. Then $E(XY)=\iint_{\mathbb{R}^2} xyf(x)g(y)\,dx\,dy$ since the joint density is the product of the individual densities (by independence). Integrating, we get $\int_{-\infty}^\infty xf(x)\,dx\int_{-\infty}^\infty yg(y)\,dy$. The discrete case is similar, somewhat simpler.

Comment: That was very affirming.  Thank you !

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Variance is a special case of covariance. The covariance operator is multilinear and symmetric, so you can write more generally that
$$\text{Var}(aX+bY) = \text{Cov}(aX+bY,aX+bY)=a\text{Cov}(X,aX+bY)+b\text{Cov}(Y,aX+bY)$$
$$=a^2\text{Cov}(X,X)+ab\text{Cov}(X,Y)+ab\text{Cov}(Y,X)+b^2\text{Cov}(Y,Y)$$
$$=a^2\text{Var}(X) + b^2\text{Var}(Y) + 2ab\text{Cov}(X,Y)$$

That is,
$$\boxed{\text{Var}(aX+bY) = a^2\text{Var}(X) + b^2\text{Var}(Y) + 2ab\text{Cov}(X,Y)}$$
where $\text{Cov}(X,Y) \stackrel{\text{def}}{=} \text{E}(XY) - \text{E}(X)\text{E}(Y)$ and $\text{Var}(X)\stackrel{\text{def}}{=}\text{Cov}(X,X)$.

Take $a=1$ and $b=\pm 1$ to get the result you want.